# When using MVVM design pattern, Is there a way to prevent Controller layer to communicate with Model layer in swift?

Tags: swift, mvvm

Typically, In the MVVM design pattern, the Controller will not directly communicate with the Model. ViewModel will be the buffer layer between C and M. However, if there is a data model in the Model like

```
struct Book
{
  var title: String
}
```

we can still define a variable in Controller like:

```
var books = [Book]()
```

In this case, the controller still can directly communicate with the Model but not through ViewModel.

Is there a way to prevent it? For example, adding an access control for the Model class or some other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach - to define public view model and interface to model, but file private model itself, so view model can manage model, but anybody outside can work with it only via public interfaces:

```
public protocol Reading {
    var title: String { get set }
}

public class BooksViewModel {
    public var books = [Reading]()

    public func createNewBook() -> Reading {
        let book = Book()
        self.books.append(book)
        return book
    }
}

fileprivate struct Book: Reading
{
  var title: String = "Undefined"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think about this way. However, in this way, Model and ViewModel will on the same file...